# Combining two rows in one select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am having a hard time combining two records (from a single table) on a single query.  The idea is, DATE_FIELD column is a date type and ColA is an integer data type.

To further illustrate my inquiry, I have attached an image below

[image]

1.) Is the raw table.
2.) Is the desired output.

P.S.  The filter for DATE_FIELD is not a simple "WHERE DATE_FIELD IN" clause.

For example, I wanted to get the DATE_FIELD=12/30/2013.  Then I need to get the Previous Sept DATE_FIELD also, which is 9/30/2013 programatically by using this query that I got from the web:

```
CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(DATE_FIELD) < 10 
            THEN 
            (cast(CAST((DATE_FIELD)  - 1) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
            ELSE 
            ( cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD)) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
END
```

Here is my current sql script (which cannot get the ColA equivalent for Previous Sept filter:

```
SELECT DATE_FIELD, ColA, 
CASE 
WHEN MONTH(DATE_FIELD) < 10 
 THEN 
 (cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD) - 1) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
 ELSE 
 ( cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD)) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
END AS PREVIOUS, 
(
 SELECT ColA 
 FROM TABLE_A
 WHERE DATE_FIELD = 
 CASE 
  WHEN MONTH(DATE_FIELD) < 10 
  THEN 
  (cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD) - 1) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
  ELSE 
  ( cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD)) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
  END
) AS PYE_colA
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE DATE_FIELD = '12/30/2013'
```

Thanks!

Comment: In this case, IMO, it matters where the output of this query goes, because combining data this way is not necessarily optimal. If you are planning to display to the user, then you'd rather not combine this way in the query, rather on the UI. If it needs to go in another DB, it is not clear from your question what basis is the data combined on. Instead of code, please explain in words how you want the data to be combined (i.e. how are dates selected to be combined in the same row).

Comment: Hi Omer, the main objective is to get the average between the selected DATE and the SEPT-Equivalent data.  I will update the image to describe how to select the rows to be combined.

Comment: I don't understand how you get to the data. You start with '12/30/2013'. There are two records for that date. Why do you display 99 and not 0? Has it something to do with StoreID (which you don't use in your query)? And then how do you get from '12/30/2013' to '09/30/2013'? Is it always the last day of the given month minus three? Or how do you get to September, and to September 30 in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a cross join with the same table and use your CASE structure only in the where clause:

```
SELECT a.DATE_FIELD AS DATE_FIELD_1,
    a.ColA AS ColA_1,
    b.DATE_FIELD AS DATE_FIELD_2,
    b.ColA AS ColA_2
FROM TABLE_A a 
CROSS JOIN TABLE_A b
WHERE DATE_FIELD_1 = 'your date'
AND DATE_FIELD_2 = (
    CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(DATE_FIELD_1) < 10 
    THEN 
        (cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD_1) - 1) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
    ELSE 
        ( cast(CAST((YEAR(DATE_FIELD_1)) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
    END)
;
```

Another possibility based on Thorsten Kettners remarks:

```
SELECT a.DATE_FIELD AS DATE_FIELD_1,
    a.ColA AS ColA_1,
    b.DATE_FIELD AS DATE_FIELD_2,
    b.ColA AS ColA_2
FROM TABLE_A a 
INNER JOIN TABLE_A b
ON b.DATE_FIELD = (
    CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(a.DATE_FIELD) < 10 
    THEN 
        (cast(CAST((YEAR(a.DATE_FIELD) - 1) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
    ELSE 
        ( cast(CAST((YEAR(a.DATE_FIELD)) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(09),2) + RIGHT('00' + LTRIM(30),2) AS Date))
    END)
WHERE a.DATE_FIELD = 'your date'
;
```

Comment: That's not really a cross join by the way. It's an inner join: *AND **b**.DATE_FIELD = (CASE **a**.DATE_FIELD ...)*. You should use INNER JOIN instead and move the clause to ON to show more clearly what you are doing. Moreover, in my opinion you obfuscate things a little by using DATE_FIELD_1/2 in your WHERE clause rather then a/b.DATE_FIELD which would show more clearly how you self-join the table.

Comment: Well to my opinion it is a cross join at first and then its rows are restricted to those matching my WHERE clause. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Yes. A cross join is where you join two tables *unrelatedly*. You build a so-called cartesian product. As you, however, join two tables *relatedly* (there is criteria how to match their records), you do an inner join actually. Only you hide this from the reader (such as to mimic the deprecated syntax `FROM a, b WHERE a.x = b.y`). Don't do this.

Comment: I tried the CROSS JOIN awhile ago and it worked.  And when Thorsten commented regarding the INNER JOIN, it also worked.  Thanks to you both!

Comment: OK thank you for the explanation. So are there any applications left for using a simple CROSS JOIN at all?

Comment: Yes, but cross joins are rare. Let's say we have a table with twelve months and another with all years. `SELECT months.name, years.year, SUM(sales.amount) FROM months CROSS JOIN years LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON sales.month_no = months.month_no AND sales.year = years.year GROUP BY months.name, years.year`. This gives you combined all months and years and sums sales where any.